# a:hover doesn't work on <div id>, help? :)

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to change color of a link on hover, but it doesn't seem to work, not sure how to solve this... here's the code:

```
<div id="secret-link" >
<a  href="/pages/our-story"><b><font color=#F44336>secret link</font></b></a>
</div>

<style>
#secret-link a:hover {color: #fff;}
</style>
```

any ideas? :/

Comment: remove the `font` tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `<font>` tags.

The styling works, but in this markup the presence of the `<font>` tag takes precedence for the actual text in place.

Replace the `<font>` with styling.  So just have the markup by itself:

```
<div id="secret-link" >
  <a href="/pages/our-story">secret link</a>
</div>
```

And then style it for the non-hover and hover states as desired:

```
#secret-link a:hover {color: #fff;}

#secret-link a {color: #f44336; font-weight: bold;}
```

Comment: Don't forget the focus and active states for people using keyboard navigation.